# Android Controlling ViewPager Scroller

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I have a horizontal viewpager with 5 views. I am trying to create a visual tutorial using parallaxing effects. I need to take control of the viewpagers srolling so I can tell the view to not scroll but still have an offset so I can move the images then resume scrolling when both images are in place.

Any ideas on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
public void onSwipeRight() {
  if(your conditionIsMet){
// move your pager view to the right
     }
   }

});
```

I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dipali. Thats not what I was looking for, I needed an offset change while disabling screen movement for parallax event. But I ended up making up my own parallax framework to create the desired effect.